# How to get back initial height value of div after if condition in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var h = $(this).parent("ul").height();
    $(".tile_nav ul li").mouseover(function() {

        var hh = $(this).children("ul").height();
        var h = $(this).parent("ul").height();

        var mainbottm = $(this).parent("ul").position().top + $(this).parent("ul").outerHeight(true);
        var bottom = $(this).children("ul").position().top + $(this).children("ul").outerHeight(true);

        var diff = bottom - mainbottm;
        var toppossub = $(".cm_rhs").offset().top;
        $(".cm_lhs h1").html("Sub UL" + bottom + "Main UL bottom " + mainbottm + " diff " + diff);
        var newulheight = h + diff;
        if (diff > 0) {
            $(".tile_nav ul").css("height", newulheight);
            s
        }
    });

    $(".tile_nav ul li").mouseleave(function() {
        $(".tile_nav ul").css("height", h);
    });
});
```

Above code working properly on mouseover. based on condition  height increasing but where can I add mouseleave for getting initial height of ?

Comment: `for getting initial height of ?` Fill in the blanks

Comment: parent <ul> ie. var h

Comment: if possible then provide fiddle please